# How can i evaluate javascript function from the function name in order to override it?

Tags: javascript

I have a function in script1 :

```
function myFunction(arg){
--code JS--
};
```

In script2, i want override this function :

```
var func_name = "myFunction";
```

How can i do to obtain body of this function from function name in order to override it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var func_name = myFunction`

Answer (score 0):

```
var func_name = myFunction; // without the quotes
```

Comment: Please provide link to doc with your answer if you can; And explain how it work

Comment: well.. you can try `console.log(myFunction);` to see that when you type the name of the function without the parenthesis it's not called ( not executed ), so `myFunction` contain a reference to the function and therefore it will display its body, and if you put it in another variable, well.. that variable will become a function as well because it contains the body of the previous function, i hope it clears it bit, i forgot where i found this, sorry i can't provide a link

Comment: I know this, but [edit] and explain it in your post : [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you are wanting to do. But you ask "How can i do to obtain body of this function from function name in order to override it?" and this is simply `.toString()` like `myFunction.toString()` This will return the entire function including the 'function() {}` outer block. To get the body, use a regex:

`function.toString().replace(/^function\ (?:\w|\d)*\([^\)]*\)\ ?\{\ *|\ *\}$/g,"")`

But to override the function you can just reassign it:

```
> function ab(){ return 1+2 }
< undefined
> ab()
< 3
> ab = function() { return 3+4 }
< function () { return 3+4 }
> ab()
< 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same name but change the functionality, use anonymous function instead:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // initial code
}
```

Reassign new function to same variable:

```
myFunction = function() {
   // new code
}
```

Call it like normal function: `myFunction()`